# Django fieldset.html customization. How to customize a single field?

Tags: django, templates, field

In my app, I need to add javascript to the admin template "fieldset.html" in order to create a widget for a single field.
But, in the fields iteration (for), when I try to catch the specific field, I fail.

I'm doing by the ifequal tag (fieldset.html):

```
    {% for line in fieldset %}
    <div class="form-row{% if line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% for field in line %} {{ field.field.name }}{% endfor %}">

        {% for field in line %}
        (...)
            {% ifequal field.label_tag "name" %}

                  #do something

            {% endifequal%}

         (...)
        {% endfor %}
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Any sugestions? The field stores the recurrence of a schedule. So I need to do something dinamic, that's why I'm thinking about using javascript.

Comment: If you just need to include some js media for a single field it's good to look at form media as ignacio propsed, if you want to check for a specific field in the template, better check with `field.name` than `label_tag`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Form Media"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/)